# How to upload multipart/form-data with enabled xsrf throw AJAX in tornadoweb

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to upload file by means POST HTTP request with enabled XSRF protection as AJAX request, but I get each time:

```
WARNING:root:403 POST /path/to/uploader/ (127.0.0.1): '_xsrf' argument missing from POST
```

I checked data of request:

```
_xsrf=01f86a98fe2346f9baec589dc8af3027&id=2
```

As I can see I send _xsrf to handler, but It can't find this argument.

If I disable multipart/form-data as contentTypem, bug will be gone and self.request.files is empty too.

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help if you include the code you have for the form.

You'll need to include the output of this in your `<form>` tag (generated in `tornado.web.RequestHandler.get()`):

```
self.xsrf_form_html()
```

If the input field is named upload_file, you can do this in the handler which handles the POST:

```
file = self.request.files['upload_file'][0]
uploaded_content_type = file['content_type']
uploaded_filename = file['filename']
local_file_path = '/some/path/on/server/uploaded.file'
output_file = open(local_file_path, 'w')
output_file.write(file['body'])
output_file.close()
```